# python error importing pyttsx

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, python-3.6, pyttsx

I have been trying to make a basic speech recognition system in python, using pyttx, however, when i run my code:

```
import speech_recognition
import pyttsx
```

I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brett\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx__init__.py", line 37, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\brett\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\weakref.py", line 131, in **getitem**
    o = self.datakey
KeyError: 'sapi5'

I have tried all solutions on here so far and none of them work, if i try to run the engine driver in pyttsx, I get an error with the driver.py, saying '**main**' is not a pack. if i have left out any other info, just let me know

Comment: I know this thread is pretty old, but has anyone found a solution with Python 3?

Comment: @Tiskolin pyttsx3